# If today's date minus db date is less than 48 hours, do something but I am getting an error. Any ideas?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Sorry again, experts for the bother again.but

We have a db date called orderdate.

If today's date - orderdate is less than 2 days (or 48 hours), disable `Cancel Order` button so user cannot cancel his or her order.

When I tried running the following code, I get `Input string not in the format`

Orderdate is of type datetime. However, we would like to display the date in the format of MM/dd/yyyy. Example: 6/4/2013, not 06/04/2013.

Can you please look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
 If dr1.Read() Then
  Dim odate As String = DateTime.Parse(dr1("orderDates").ToString()).ToShortDateString()

  Dim cancelBtn As New Button()
  Dim dates As String = DateTime.Parse(Now().ToString()).ToShortDateString()
   If (sdate - dates) <2 Then
       cancelBtn.Enabled = False
   Else
       cancelBtn.Enabled = True
   End If
 End If
```

---

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    ' Create cancel training button
    Dim cancelBtn As New Button()
    cancelBtn.Style.Add("width", "105px")
    cancelBtn.Style.Add("padding", "5px")
    cancelBtn.Style.Add("margin", "5px")
    'cancelBtn.Enabled = False
    cancelBtn.Text = "Cancel training"
    If e.Row.RowIndex > "-1" Then
        ' Change tracking ID to link
        'Dim track As [String] = e.Row.Cells(4).Text
        'If track <> "&nbsp;" AndAlso track.Length > 0 Then
        '    Dim trackLink As New Literal()
        '    trackLink.Text = "<a style='color: blue;' href='" + track + "'/>Track</a>"
        '    e.Row.Cells(4).Controls.Add(trackLink)
        'End If

        ' Add buttons to column
        Dim oid As [String] = e.Row.Cells(0).Text
        Dim invoiceLink As New Literal()
        invoiceLink.Text = "<a style='color: blue;' href='Invoice.aspx?oid=" + oid + "'/>" + oid + "</a>"
        e.Row.Cells(0).Controls.Add(invoiceLink)
        e.Row.Cells(e.Row.Cells.Count - 1).Controls.Add(cancelBtn)

        ' Pass order id & row to on-click event
        'cancelBtn.Click += new EventHandler(this.cancelBtn_Click);
        'cancelBtn.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex + "-" + oid
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why convert these to strings?  Leaving as dates you can use built in datetime functions.  And what is sdate in your if statement above -- should that be odate?

Comment: yes @sgeddes. Sorry, typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Regarding the logic, your DB field `orderDates` sounds like it refers to the day the order was created.  That date will always be in the past, so we would be interested in `Today - orderDates`.

However, based on your comments it seems `orderDates` refers to the day the order will ship.  That date must be more than 2 days in the future for the user to cancel his order, so we're interested in `orderDates - Today`.

I don't see where you run the order date logic inside `GridView1_RowDataBound`.

```
Private Function MoreThanTwoDaysUntilShip() As Boolean
    'logic to open dr1
    If dr1.Read() Then
        Dim shipDate As Date = DateTime.Parse(dr1("orderDates").ToString())
        Dim today As Date = Date.Now

        Return shipDate.Subtract(today).TotalDays > 2
    End If

    Return False
End Function

Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    ' Create cancel training button
    Dim cancelBtn As New Button()
    cancelBtn.Style.Add("width", "105px")
    cancelBtn.Style.Add("padding", "5px")
    cancelBtn.Style.Add("margin", "5px")

    'add this
    cancelBtn.Enabled = MoreThanTwoDaysUntilShip()


    'etc
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you @just.

The issue I am having with this line:

`Return dates.Subtract(odate).TotalDays < 2` is that it isn't working like it is supposed to.

If the cancellation date is within 2 days, then disable the `Cancel Order` button.

So far, it disables or enables the `Cancel Order` based on the direction of the arrow rather than based on date difference.

For instance, if the direction of the arrow is > 2, it doesn't matter if there are 10 days left or 1 day left on the day of order cancellation, the `Cancel Order` button is disabled. You can the direction, the button is enabled.

Comment: @Kenny Sorry, corrected the logic to use `> 2` as your question indicated.  Can you attach a debugger and verify what the actual values of `dates` and `odate` are before the `Subtract` happens?

Comment: @just.another.programmer2, If I run your code as is, the value of odate is 6/24/2013  and the value of dates is 6/5/2013 3:35:57.

As you can see, one has date and time.

However, if use this:
`Dim odate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(dr1("trainingDates").ToString())
Dim dates As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(Now().ToString()).ToShortDateString()`, I same value of MM/dd/yyyy.

But I am still having issues. It doesn't matter what the value of odate is, it can disable or enable based solely on > or <.

Not really sure what's wrong here.

Comment: `6/24/2013` is *in the future*... `dates.Subtract(odate).TotalDays` will be **-19** and thus obviously less than 2!

Comment: Then the logic isn't correct.

I said that because let's assume that order is scheduled to ship 6/24/2013 but the user wants to cancel the order before it ships.

The user has up till 6/21 (3 days before order ships) to cancel it.

So, if you say that using `dates.Subtract(odate).TotalDays`  means that 6/24/2013 is -19, then it doesn't help us. We want the user to see it as having 19 days before order ships which means the user has 16 days to cancel the order.

Can you please help rewrite it?

Comment: That means `odate` is not the date the item was ordered, but a *shipment date*.  You want to subtract `dates` from `odate`.  `odate.Subtract(dates).TotalDays`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you'd want to convert your date fields into strings.  I would recommend leaving those as datetime objects for your comparison.  You can always manipulate the display of the dates in your presentation logic.

This is some working code leaving as dates using `Subtract` and `TotalDays`:

```
Dim cancelBtn As New Button()
Dim odate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(dr1("orderDates").ToString())
Dim dates As DateTime = DateTime.Now()

If dates.Subtract(odate).TotalDays >= 2 Then
    cancelBtn.Enabled = False
Else
    cancelBtn.Enabled = True
End If
```

You could also consolidate the `If` statement to a single line:

```
cancelBtn.Enabled = dates.Subtract(odate).TotalDays < 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much @sgeddes. Thank you. The error is gone but it isn't having any effect. Should I move it to rowdatabound? Please see snip above.

I will be glad to post this as a separate question if that's what I have to do.

Comment: Sorry @sgeddes,

I think the reason it is not working is because we are getting 2 separate date formats.

odate has this date value: `6/4/2013` while dates has the following value: `6/5/2013 12:29:28 AM'

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Parse(Now().ToString()).ToShortDateString()
```

Replace with

```
Today
```

And otherwise, don't manipulate dates in strings.